# Unable to share the data between different components using react Context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context, react-component

Created two components like class(ABC) and function(XYZ)respectively.Both are independent components. 
loading the table data in ABC component and trying to pass it XYZ component using Context. 
I am not getting the idea where exactly making the mistake. see the code..

**inside ABC.js**

```
//excluding imports
export const MContext = React.createContext();
export default class ABC extends Component {
. //inside componentDidMount(){} loading resultsArray
.
.
.
handleClick(){
        this.showGrid = true;
}
 render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <MContext.Provider value={{resultsArray}} >

                </MContext.Provider>
.
.
.
<div>
   <button  onClick = {this.handleClick}>Submit</button>
   { this.state.showGrid ? <XYZ/> : null }
 </div>
</div>
}
```

**and Inside XYZ.js**

```
const rows = [];
export default function XYZ() {

    <div>
        <Mcontext.Consumer>
            {(context) => (
                rows = context.value
            )}
        </Mcontext.Consumer>
    </div>
.
.
.
}
```

But here I am unable to transfer the resultsArray[] into rows[] rather getting an exception:

Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression

at  in XYZ.js, any clue will be appreciated.

**Note:** `<div><Mcontext.Consumer>`... is inside the render() function

Comment: is ABC component child of XYZ component?

Comment: no both are independent components

Answer (score 0):

`context` api in react is used only for passing data from parent to child components.This is mainly to avoid passing `props` down the tree for multiple levels.

```
   <MContext.Provider value={value} >
            <Component/>
    </MContext.Provider>
```

by doing this `Component` and all its children can access `context` value.

In your case, context cannot be used for sharing data between independent components. In that case you need to life the state up.
Here

```
<MContext.Provider value={{resultsArray}} >

 </MContext.Provider>
```

you did not wrap `Context.Provider` with any Component. So that won't work